# Why is there an error with the source command in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to add the employee sample database for practicing with MySQL however there's an error since there's a source command and from what I've found it says that MySQL doesn't support this command anymore.

So, how could I add the complete database without any error?

[this is the code line where the source command is called]

[image: 1]

Comment: Please share more details, like the command you are using, the error message you are facing, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

`SOURCE` is one of the mysql client builtin commands. These are recognized by the mysql client, but not by the MySQL Server's SQL parser.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html